USB connector: inward positioning relative to front panel
I am going to use 292336-1 USB connector and having difficulties figuring out the information on recommended inward offset relative to front panel surface.
The datasheet, in its recommended PCB layout, shows only front of the connector, but not front of the panel the connector is being positioned against. I suspect being flush is the wrong position, and looking to other devices, in particular notebooks, I see that USB connector is inward to the front panels, and also external USB mating connectors have longer "nose" allowing PCB-mounted connectors being slightly inwards - suspect for not allowing finger and other foreign objects to touch/reach parts of the connector and its contacts easily.
Has Anyone seen related guidelines? Please share this information.
Update: here's the answer for those looking for the solution, and thinking that the user experience people get from the electronics and engineering work they do matters.
The datasheets seem not list this aspect for their connectors, however I think they should. Two documents are involved: the datasheet for the connector itself:

which shows (or does no show) the stop for the mating connector, in this case the depth is 8.88 mm. And my measurements show that datasheet may be wrong, 8.88 mm is a distance from the stop (plastic inner wall) and the inner radius surface on the bend, but let's discount it for tolerances.
Second document is called "USB ‘A’ Plug Form Factor Revision 1.0: A Form Factor Guideline for Embedded USB Device Applications' (link).

It shows min 11.75 mm for the nose of the USB type A connector.
Therefore the slack between the connector edge and the USB stick body is expected to be 11.75 - 8.88 = 2.87 mm, and you may plan this connector's inner offset appropriately.

you asked a yes/no question ... it would make more sense to ask where can be found?

I’m voting to close this question because this is a Mechanical/Industrial/UX design question, Not an Electrical Engineering one.

@brhans disagree, mechanical specifications of the electronic parts are not related to electronics? Let's vote for manufacturers removing package specifications and pinouts from the datasheets because they are not related to electrical engineering? I believe you must give more substantial reasons before clicking downvote and close buttons.

You're not asking about the mechanical specs of that part - those are (presumably) detailed in the datasheet. What you're asking about it how you should position the part in relation to its enclosure in order to provide a particular user experience. That's not Electrical Engineering, and the fact that you, as an Electrical Engineer, might be doing this work doesn't make it Electrical Engineering.

@brhans Wikipedia: "Electrical engineering is an engineering discipline concerned with the study, design, and application of equipment, devices, and systems which use electricity, electronics, and electromagnetism".
